# How to aggregate specific cells from grid?

Tags: kendo-ui

I am trying to create this grid and chart using KendoUi. 
[SalesOverrides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Berdw.png)
This is what I have so far. My question is how can I aggregate the cells of Data - Orders(lbs) for All - CustomerType with each CustomerType value, so that when one is changed the other one would be reflected?

Thanks,
Jordan Michael

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is specify the pertinent aggregate function name via the columns->aggregates. Here is a sample:

```
 group: {
            field: "CustomerType", aggregates: [                  
                  { field: "May18", aggregate: "sum" },
                  { field: "May18", aggregate: "sum" },
                  { field: "Jun18", aggregate: "sum" },
                  { field: "Jul18", aggregate: "sum" },
                  //  ...
                 ]
        },
```

Check also the templates for the footer results documentation: https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/aggregates

Comment: I guess I'll need to use another component to implement this https://imgur.com/a/P2VHX2i . I'm currently looking at TreeList Examples ( https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/remote-data-binding ) using json data from server. Can you give some advice on creating this treelist?

Comment: Tree list also allows aggregates. Here is the documentation from telerik. https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/aggregates . What is the reason why you give up the grid? Did you try my answer?

Comment: I could not find a way to implement this structure https://imgur.com/a/P2VHX2i using a normal grid.